# Bypassing Ember validation while injecting a user and pass with jquery val

Tags: jquery, ember.js

As a hobby I am trying to build my own username and password storage to inject via chrome plugin from site to site.

It works fine with the usual `$('#username').val()`
However I am coming up against an issue on a site that was built with ember.
The site has a form like this:

```
<form class="login_form" novalidate="" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-7="7" _lpchecked="1">
    <div id="ember4" class="fieldset fieldset--error fieldset--empty fieldset--material ember-view"> <label for="username" class="fieldset_label">Username</label> <input name="username" id="username" class="input username" autocomplete="off" autofocus=""></div>
</form>
```

The problem is when I use `$('#username').val("myUsername");`

I get an error that says "please enter a username". The thing is if I go into the input, press any key, and then delete the text that I added it validates because it removes fieldset--error and fieldset--empty which then allows me to press submit and it works.

The thing is - how do I solve this in a programmatic way? Is there a way to tell Ember to stop pestering me to manually type instead of using .val()?

Or is there a way to trick it into thinking I did (because jquery.trigger doesn't work)

Comment: would you mind giving us the URL of this Ember.js app?

Comment: single page apps / javascript libraries / frameworks listen to events on the inputs, so setting the value of the input typically won't be enough. While triggering a change or input event may be enough (they are the most common events listened to on inputs), people may listen to other events instead... so it really depends on the implementation of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100%ly sure but I guess the issue you are facing is caught by not triggering the `change` event. `jQuery.val()` does not do so:

> Setting values using this method (or using the native value property) does not cause the dispatch of the change event. For this reason, the relevant event handlers will not be executed. If you want to execute them, you should call .trigger( "change" ) after setting the value.
>
> https://api.jquery.com/val/

You could either do it with `jQuery.trigger('change')` or refactor to use native browser APIs. The ember community has a set of test helpers that try to simulate normal browser behavior as much as possible. They are developed and provided as [`@ember/test-helpers`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers) package. It comes with a [`fillIn`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/master/API.md#fillin) test helper that does what you are trying to achieve.

I would not recommend using `@ember/test-helpers` in your project directly as that adds another dependency for a simple task. Instead you could just use there implementation as a blueprint: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/v1.6.1/addon-test-support/@ember/test-helpers/dom/fill-in.ts

Simplified it should look like this:

```js
function fillIn(selector, value) {
  // TODO: Assert that selector does not match more than one element.
  let element = document.querySelector(selector);

  // TODO: Firefox does not trigger the `focusin` event if the window
  //       does not have focus.
  element.focus();

  // TODO: Handle elements that aren't a control.
  element.value = value;

  element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}
```

This may cause async work. So you should await that work to be finished before proceeding. Ember comes with a [`settled`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/v1.6.1/API.md#settled) test helper therefore. As this one is ember-specific it won't work on other projects. But you may find inspiration by the [`waitFor()`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/v1.6.1/API.md#waitfor) and [`waitUntil()`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/v1.6.1/API.md#waituntil), which let you await a specific state of the UI. But that would be a topic for another question.